# How to concatenate string and pass to a system() call?

Tags: c++

I have a bit of code here that I'm trying to use to allow the user to put in an IP address and have the code ping it. I'm just doing through the system() function right now. My problem is that I can't have the system() function read a string as well as a variable. Have a look here:

```
system("ping " + INPUT);
```

INPUT is already defined earlier, as a string, and it holds the IP address that the user puts into the program to ping. If I use the + operator, Visual Studio gives me an error because I'm using a mathematical operator on two strings. What operator do I use to combine the contents of two different strings?

Comment: system((std::string("ping ") + INPUT).c_str());

Comment: ...and this is no "And" operator, this is plus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not with the string concatenation. It is that `system` requires a pointer to `char`, not an `std:: string`. So you need something like

```
std::string s2 = "ping" + INPUT;
system(s2.c_str());
```

Comment: Or just `system(("ping"+INPUT).c_str())`

Comment: @Cramer Minimizing lines of code doesn't always improve code quality.

Comment: @moooeeeep Is there any problem with the code quality in this case? Just to know.

Answer (score 2):

When/if you're doing this very often, the obvious route of building a string, then calling `system(your_string.c_str());` can be somewhat annoying.

To make such a situation somewhat more palatable, I once wrote this code that you might want to consider:

exec.hpp:

```
#ifndef EXEC_HPP_INC_
#define EXEC_HPP_INC_

#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>

inline std::ostream &execute(std::ostream &s) {
    std::ostringstream &ss = dynamic_cast<std::ostringstream &>(s);
    std::system(ss.str().c_str());
    return s;
}

inline std::ostringstream &operator<<(std::ostringstream &s,
                          std::ostringstream &(*manip)(std::ostringstream &s))
{
    return manip(s);
}

#endif
```

Usage is something like this:

```
#include "exec.hpp"

std::ostringstream x;

x << "ping " << INPUT << execute;
```

Answer (score 0):

system takes const char pointer **not** string.
You can append "INPUT" to ping command and build the string earlier.