# How can I open several images from a C++ program using terminal commands?

Tags: c++

I need to open several images from a website generating the url of the image with a for cycle - all the urls look the same but for the final number.

system("open") works fine for a single url, but I don't know how to pass the variable referring to the number of the image inside the command, being it a string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++)
    {
        system("open http://www.site/images/image-[how do I pass i here??].jpg");
    }
}
```

[Edit] I'm working on MacOS.

Comment: On which operating system? By definition, the behavior of `system` is operating system specific.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/191757/560648 https://stackoverflow.com/q/22140333/560648

Comment: But `open` when passed to `system` don't behave the same on MacOSX, on Linux, on Windows.

Comment: Okay to be fair for a broader solution per the _title_ we would want to know what the platform is

Answer (score 1):

You should *build* dynamically the C string passed to `system`.

For example:

```
for (int i=1; i<=13; i++) {
  char cmdbuf[80];
  snprintf(cmdbuf, sizeof(cmdbuf), "open http://www.site/images/image-%d.jpg", i);
  int notok = system(cmdbuf);
  if (notok) break;
}
```

the above is actually C code (which, with appropriate `#include`-s, would work in C++). If you want genuine C++ code you might use some [std::ostringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to build some [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) (and convert it into a C string using its [`c_str`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) member function before passing that to [`system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system))

Read about `snprintf` in [C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) and in [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf). C and C++ are *different* languages.

In C++, [`std::system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) is provided with `<cstdlib>` (which you should use instead of [`<stdlib.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program) which is a C standard header).

BTW, you might be interested by HTTP server libraries such as [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) and by HTTP client libraries such as [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). You'll better understand much more about the [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) protocol.

Your above program is better and faster written as a [shell script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script). For your particular case it would be faster (to write), and more robust (even if perhaps it runs a few milliseconds slower). Notice that `open` is not a standard POSIX program (on Linux, you would use [`xdg-open`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open) instead) and might not exist on Windows (which I don't know at all).

Notice also that neither the C standard nor the POSIX standard guarantee that the user of your program has a screen. If you run your program on some datacenter machine, you might be disappointed.

Comment: Can confirm, no joy with `open` on Windows 10 at least

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I do appreciate the detailed and insightful answer. But as you've for sure understood my question comes from a total beginner point of view, hence I consider Lightness Races in Orbit's comment to be the correct answer, since there I found the straightforward answer (...) label = to_string(i);
url_full = url_start + label + url_ending; system(url_full.c_str());